# ./PacketTracer7 error: libcrypto.so.1.0.0

Tags: installation, kali-linux, libraries

I'm currently trying to install Packet Tracer on Kali Linux (as root). Upon running `./PacketTracer7` in `/opt/pt/bin`, I got the following error:

```
./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've seen that `libssl1.0.0` seems to pop up in troubleshoots related to this so I tried `apt update` and `apt install libssl1.0.0` but to no avail. `apt install libssl1.0.0` returns the following error:

```
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate
```

Just in case, I also tried `apt install libcrypto.so.1.0.0` but the package also couldn't be found.

When looking into /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, I found 2 files: `libcrypto.so.1.1` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.2`. I copied them to `/opt/pt/bin` and retried `./PacketTracer7` but still got the error:

```
./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How should I fix the error with `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` to continue with my installation of Packet Tracer?